# Recursive function in Python not finding date in Excel Sheet

Tags: python, excel, recursion

I'm trying to make a script for work that needs to find the closest (past or future) date to a given date in an Excel Sheet. There are 2 main functions:

The find_date function iterates over a sheet to find a match of a given date in a worksheet, I've tested it multiple times and it works fine. Returns -1 when the date is not found.

```
def find_date(date, wsRows):
    for row in wsRows:
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value == date:
                return cell.row
    else:
        return -1
```

The other function is a recursive one, if the given date doesn't exist in the worksheet, it adds or subtract a day (user's choice) and tries again until a match:

```
def find_closest_date(date, wsRows, searchType):
    #searchType is 0 to search for previous dates and 1 to search for future dates
    nextDate = date
    result = find_date(date, wsRows)

    if result == -1:
        if searchType== 0:
            nextDate -= timedelta(days=1)            
        else:
            nextDate += timedelta(days=1)

        find_closest_date(nextDate , wsRows, searchType)
    else:
        return result
```

The problem here is that I cannot make the recursive function find any date until the recursion depth limit (even if the closest date is like 5 days in the past), except if I provide an existing date as the first input.

Here is the full minimal working example, I appreciate any help you can give me on the topic

```
import openpyxl
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def find_date(date, wsRows):
    for row in wsRows:
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value == date:
                return cell.row
    else:
        return -1


def find_closest_date(date, wsRows, searchType):
    #searchType is 0 to search for previous dates and 1 to search for future dates
    nextDate = date
    result = find_date(date, wsRows)

    if result == -1:
        if searchType== 0:
            nextDate -= timedelta(days=1)
        else:
            nextDate += timedelta(days=1)

        find_closest_date(nextDate , wsRows, searchType)
    else:
        return result


startDate = datetime.strptime('2021-01-18', '%Y-%m-%d')

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\\PATH\\TO\\FILE.xlsx', read_only=True)
ws = wb['SHEET']

print(str(startDate) + " (" + str(type(startDate)) + ") " + str(find_date(startDate, ws.rows)))

endDate = datetime.strptime('2021-02-16', '%Y-%m-%d') #This date does not exist in the worksheet, the closest one is 2021-02-13

print(str(endDate) + " (" + str(type(endDate)) + ") " + str(find_date(endDate, ws.rows)))

print(find_closest_date(endDate, ws.rows, 0))

wb.close()
```

The output of this code is as follows:

```
2021-01-18 00:00:00 (<class 'datetime.datetime'>) 1739
2021-02-16 00:00:00 (<class 'datetime.datetime'>) -1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\test\test.py", line 40, in <module>
    print(find_closest_date(endDate, ws.rows, 0))
  File "D:\Python\test\test.py", line 24, in find_closest_date
    find_closest_date(nextDate , wsRows, searchType)
  File "D:\Python\test\test.py", line 24, in find_closest_date
    find_closest_date(nextDate , wsRows, searchType)
  File "D:\Python\test\test.py", line 24, in find_closest_date
    find_closest_date(nextDate , wsRows, searchType)
  [Previous line repeated 995 more times]
  File "D:\Python\test\test.py", line 16, in find_closest_date
    result = find_date(date, wsRows)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: `date` is a `datetime` object and `cell.value` is a `str` object. Comparing them with `cell.value == date` will always give `False`. I would suggest using `strftime` at the beginning of `find_closest_date` to whip it into the format that you need.

Comment: Sadly that didn't work because the dates are being converted to datetime automatically. Besides that the find_date function works properly when called on its own (check the first print statement)